# Integral in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I was trying to find the integral "final2" below and I got this error:

```
"This can happen when it's not possible to detect zero in the coefficient domain. the domain of computation is RR[_X3,_X4,_X8,_X9,_X10]. Zero detection is guaranteed in this coefficient domain. This may indicate a bug in SymPy or the domain is user defined and doesn't implement zero detection properly"
```

I tried to use `simplify` and `nsimplify` but the code was running for more than 3 days and still did not get any answer.

Is it possible that the limits of the integration could be the source of the problem, since they are not fixed? If that's the case, what can I do about it? Is there a better library or command I can use to solve this?

```
from sympy import *

#Fist define the constants' values
e=1.6*10**-19
hbar=1.05*10**-34
mstar=9.1*10**-31
m=0.22*9.1*10**-31
ab=hbar**2/e**2

#Define variables
d, k, phi, theta ,q, w, Vgr, Vp= symbols('d k phi theta q w Vgr Vp')

#intermediate variables 
ez1w=5.8 * (w**2-738.3**2)/(w**2-533**2)
et1w=5.35 * (w**2-745**2)/(w**2-744**2) 
ez2w=5.8 * (w**2-659.3**2)/(w**2-888**2)
et2w=5.35 * (w**2-671.6**2)/(w**2-895**2)
eta1= sqrt(abs(ez1w*et1w))
eta2= sqrt(abs(ez2w*et2w))
alpha=0.5*eta1
ek=hbar**2*k**2/(2*m)
eq=hbar**2*q**2/(2*m)
nw=1/(exp(hbar*w/25.9)-1)

#Define D function
DIf=(pi**4)*((alpha*(q**2)*(d**2)*(pi**2+(alpha*q*d)**2)**2)*(((1-eta1**2)*alpha*q*d+eta1)*2*(alpha**2)*diff(ez1w,w)+((1-eta1**2)*alpha*q*d+eta1)*0.5*diff(et1w,w)))**-1

#temp1=qn+k*cos(theta)-m*v/hbar
#temp2=0.5*qn+m*(Vp-Vgr)/hbar
temp3=0.5*q+(m/hbar)*(Vp-Vgr)
#temp4=(2*mstar/ab)*(Dc*(nw+1)/temp2)
temp5=sqrt(1/m*(2*ek-0.5*eq+hbar*w)-Vp**2)
temp7=((Vp/q+hbar/(2*m))*1/Vgr-1/q)

#The scattering rate equation is defined as final2
final2=(2*m/ab)*DIf*(nw)*temp7/(temp3*temp5)

#Integration Limits
lower=hbar*q**2/(2*m)+k*q*hbar/m
upper=hbar*q**2/(2*m)-k*q*hbar/m

#Do the integration
print('Scattering Rate is given by:')
SR = integrate(final2, (w, lower, upper))
```

Comment: How does this involve Matlab? It looks like Python with Sympy to me.

Comment: It does not. I'm saying if it's possible to work this problem in MATLAB that would be okay. Perhaps the tag was misleading. I apologize!

Comment: Yeah, tags should generally indicate what tools or methods are actually involved in the question. Don't count on a tag to indicate something that you don't explicitly mention in the question body. Plus, asking how to do this with MATLAB is a separate question; probably best to keep this one limited to Python. I've fixed the tags for you.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed Judging from the expression of `final2`, it should not be surprising that sympy fails to find the integral. Any symbolic software would fail as well. You have to try a different approach. Since you are considering floating point values, it appears that a *numerical* integration is probably appropriate for your case (of course, this would mean substituting all parameters in `final2` other than `w` with numerical values).

Comment: @Stelios  Thank you for your response. Just re-did the equation. I have all the variables in final2 as functions of w. I am still getting an error that the limits are invalid. Which command should I use now?